# String concatenation via ++ or <>

Tags: haskell

I'm wondering whether there is a reason to use one over the other for string concatenation:

```
λ> "foo" ++ "bar"
"foobar"
λ> "foo" <> "bar"
"foobar"
```

Operator `++` is defined as list concatenation while `<>` is an associative binary operator of a semigroup. In `GHC.Base` we even have that for lists they are the same:

```
instance Semigroup [a] where
        (<>) = (++)
```

Is there any pro/con to use one over the other? Typically I prefer `<>` since this means I can switch between types `String` and `Text` more easily. Any other pros/cons?

Comment: I wouldn't use `<>` over `++` unless i am really `mappend`ing for some reason. `<>` is a very overloaded operator.  For instance `(drop <> take) 2` rotates a `String` by 2 places in which case `<>` is used as a `++` (under the Semigroup instance of `(a -> b)`) which is purposeful. Otherwise i would always stick to `++` otherwise it could easily become a source of confusion.

Comment: @Redu I don't see your point, but why don't you elaborate as another answer? — `>>=` is also a very overloaded operator (and by extension `do`), yet nobody would think to use anything else for sequencing `IO` actions.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Definitely `(>>=)` is preferable for `IO`, but I know that I prefer using `concatMap` to `(>>=)` when it makes the code more readable and there’s nothing inherently monadic about what I’m doing. Possibly Redu meant something similar — `(<>)` is fine, but use `(++)` when concatenating `String`s as it’s clearer with less context. (Of course I’m not Redu, so I have no way of knowing if this speculation is correct.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes as @bradm read my comment correctly what i am saying is `<>` is concatenation under a certain abstraction (Semigroups and Monoids). The example in my comment demonstrates this. `<>` beautifully becomes a `++` only after we apply `<>` to 2 functions with a List / String type return value and that chains up nicely. `>>=` is also a part of a certain abstraction, to chain up monadic actions / resolutions. I am sure you would prefer using `concat` instead of `>>= id` under normal circumstances right..?

Comment: @Redu no, I would prefer using [`join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join). (Or [`mconcat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mconcat).)

Answer (score 6):

I agree, `<>` is preferrable because it works on text types other than `Prelude.String`.

The only downside I can think of: more polymorphism can also mean that the types become ambiguous. Specifically, when `-XOverloadedStrings` is active, you can't just pass a string literal to an input-polymorphic function anymore. Sometimes just a little bit of extra information helps resolve these ambiguities. When using `++`, the compiler knows it must be a list representation, and then the `a ~ Char` constraint in the `IsString [a]` instance is sufficient to infer that you want it to be a plain old `String`. But when you're using `<>`, it's likely enough that one of the operands already constrains the type anyway, and also it's arguable whether it might be better to always add an explicit signature in ambiguous situations, rather than relying on subtle details like `++` vs `<>`.